# What is meant by the rank of the scoring function here?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, papers, recommender-system, knowledge-graph, knowledge-graph-embeddings

I've been reading the paper [Reinforcement Knowledge Graph Reasoning for Explainable Recommendation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.05237.pdf) (by Yikun Xian et al.) lately, and I don't understand a particular section:

> Specifically, the scoring function $f((r,e)|u)$ maps any edge $(r,e)$ to a real-valued score conditioned on user $u$. Then, the user-conditional pruned action space of state $s_t$ denoted by $A_t(u)$ is defined as:
>
> $A_t(u) = \{(r,e)| rank(f((r,e)|u))) \leq \alpha ,(r,e) \in A_t\} $
>
> where $\alpha$ is a predefined integer that upper bounds the size of the action space.

Details about the scoring function can be found in the attached paper.

What I don't understand is: **What does rank mean, here? Is the thing inside of it a matrix?**

It would be great if someone could explain the expression for the user conditional pruned action space in greater detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{rank}(f((r,e)|u))$ in $A_t(u)$ means to compute the value of scoring function $f$ for all pairs $(r,e)\in A_t$ which are conditioned by $u$, then sort them in a descending order. The rank of the $f((r,e)|u)$ in this order is equal to $\text{rank}(f((r,e)|u))$. Hence $\text{rank}(f((r,e)|u)) \leqslant \alpha$ means to select the $\alpha$ top most scored pairs.